# Inherit the files from parent theme in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent-child

After long time I am again making WordPress child theme. I know every parts of the WordPress that I need to know about creating child theme. But this time I am not able to make child theme that inherits parents theme.
What happened in my case?

**style.css file**:

```
/*
Theme Name: ifn child theme
Them URI: ifn.org.np
Description: This is child theme of ifn
Author:suku
Author URI:suku.com.np
Template: ifn
Version:1.0
*/
@import url('../ifn/style.css');
```

Comment: try this : @import url("../ifn/style.css"); go through this http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes..it would help you

Comment: Sorry for the inconvieniences as i had made simple mistake in naming the theme as ifn-child.

Answer (score 0):

You also can add your parent style-sheet using following code:-

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_styles' );
function load_my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

Hope this will help you.!